# Is there a way to open Swift Playground without restarting Xcode 6?

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift-playground

Is there a way to open Swift Playground without shutting down Xcode and restarting? I am not seeing it available anywhere except when Xcode is started from scratch.

Comment: you could also right-click on the dock icon and if you've previously opened it, it should be in the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hit Command-Shift-1 to open the 'Welcome to Xcode' window. Then select the 'Get started with a playground' option.

Alternatively, select it in the Window menu:

[image]

It's the 6th item down.

Comment: You can also use File->New->File... and choose between a new iOS or  OS X playground file. (You can also add a playground file to an existing project this way.)